# Execute string in same terminal

Tags: powershell

I'm coming from Linux with Bash and Zsh and now I'm working with Windows Powershell. I'm working on a JavaScript NodeJs project and I want to use command execution in Powershell, e.g. in Bash I can write

```
$(npm bin)/tsc -v
```

This will call `npm bin` (which returns something of the form `node_modules/.bin`), concatenate the result with `/tsc` and call the whole line, equivalent to

```
node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
```

I read about command execution in Powershell but it seems that this only works in strings. The line

```
$(npm bin)/tsc -v
```

causes the error

```
At line:1 char:12
+ $(npm bin)/tsc -v
+            ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:12
+ $(npm bin)/tsc -v
+            ~~~
Unexpected token 'tsc' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

and the line

```
$(npm bin)\tsc -v
```

causes the error

```
At line:1 char:11
+ $(npm bin)\tsc -v
+           ~~~~
Unexpected token '\tsc' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

So I created the string

```
"$(npm bin)/tsc"
```

and called it with

```
& "$(npm bin)/tsc" -v
```

But this opens a new terminal, calls the command with argument in the new terminal, closes the terminal and I can't see the result. How can I call this string in the same terminal? Is there a typical Powershell way to achieve this?

Comment: PowerShell is an OOP language. PowerShell will allow you to run any external executable in the console-host, ISE, and VSCode, but they must be coded properly, including proper command string quoting and terminations. This is specifically documented here: [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) as well as understanding [about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7).

Comment: @postanote Thanks for your links but I'm not sure how this could help me. I'm already using _"5. The Call Operator &"_ and it doesn't work. I tried _"2. Invoke-Expression (IEX)"_ `Invoke-Expression "$(npm bin)/tsc -v"` with the same result. A new window opens and closes and I'm not able to see the result.